# Can Host Mac OS access web server located at Guest Windows 7 in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, mac, networking, virtualbox

I wonder if it's possible to access jboss web server which I can access in virtual box windows 7 as guest using localhost:8080 on mac as host?

The current network is NAT. Do I need to change it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NAT. Just use port forwarding under the settings for the VM.

Answer (score 0):

As v1k1ng said, you can use NAT, but make sure that instead of accessing the jboss web server through the address `localhost:8080`, that you use the IP of the guest instead to access it.

You can get the IP of the guest by opening `cmd` in the guest OS and typing in `ipconfig /all`.